# Most frequent value per aggregated group or rule in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following toy dataset:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                     'text':['Dax','Dax','Dax','Pau','Tarbes','Tarbes','Tarbes','Muret'],
                     'group':['meme','meme','gif','pic','gif','all','gif','pic']})
mydf
    id  text    group
0   1   Dax     meme
1   2   Dax     meme
2   3   Dax     gif
3   4   Pau     pic
4   5   Tarbes  gif
5   6   Tarbes  all
6   7   Tarbes  meme
7   8   Muret   pic
```

And I want to aggregate by `text` selecting only the most frequent value of `group`, except in the case that group is `all`, then try to prefer other options instead of `all` if possible.

This is the expected result:

```
    text    group
0   Dax     meme
1   Pau     pic
2   Tarbes  gif
3   Muret   pic
```

I tried this, but it's a little messy (not returning a df) and I don't figure out how to put the `all` condition:

```
mydf.groupby(['text'])['group'].max()

text
Dax       meme
Muret      pic
Pau        pic
Tarbes     gif
Name: group, dtype: object
```

Please any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
out = mydf.groupby('text')['group'].agg(lambda x : x.mode().loc[lambda x : x!='all'].iloc[0] if len(x)>1 else x.mode().iloc[0])
Out[111]: 
text
Dax       meme
Muret      pic
Pau        pic
Tarbes     gif
Name: group, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hello @BENY, this answer made me learn how to put a lambda function inside an aggregation, thank you. Just a question please, the returned result doesn't look like a data frame, and the `group` name of the second column is missing. How can I see it as the expected result in my question?

Comment: @Alexis adding reset_index() at the end